# How to disable and uninstall a Drupal module programmatically?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to be able to disable and then uninstall a module programmatically on my local environment and then easily push that code to prod so everything gets updated.

I'm guessing it's something with the [`hook_update_N`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x). But not sure where to start.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Think I found the answer! Within the modules .install file, I added this code:

```
/**
 * Disable and uninstall the module.
 */
function MODULE_update_7200() {
  if( module_exists('MODULE')) {
    module_disable(array('MODULE'));
    drupal_uninstall_modules(array('MODULE'));
  }
}
```

The number in the function should reflect your drupal install. See how to number them here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7

Answer (score 11):

## Drupal 8

In Drupal 8 this is only one step now.

To be placed inside `MYMODULE.install`:

```
/**
 * Uninstall Field UI.
 */
function MYMODULE_update_8001(&$sandbox) {

  \Drupal::service('module_installer')->uninstall(['field_ui']);

}
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, this also works in Drupal 9. Even when starting the update number with an 800X.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8 you can use configuration API to enable and disable modules.
For example, if you want to enable devel module. You have to add following code to the core.extension.yml
`devel: 0`
If you want to uninstall you have to remove `devel: 0` from the core.extension.yml

Comment: This is step 2. Step 1 would be to have it exported initially `drush cex`. Then your step. And then step 3: re-import the config `drush cim`. But actually that's not what OP is asking for. The question is: **programmatically**.

Comment: In some circumstances it may not be possible to do a configuration import without first disabling a module in an update hook.

Answer (score 1):

you can use drush and forcefully uninstall the module just like the following:

```
drush eval "\$module_data = \Drupal::config('core.extension')->get('module'); unset(\$module_data['MODULE_NAME']); \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('core.extension')->set('module', \$module_data)->save();"
```